# How to get contents of the column in reverse order in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So I'm new to selenium and java. I have been having problems sorting a dataTable. What I wanted to do is to click the Name column and sort it in reverse order (because by default, the sorting is in alphabetical order). The problem is when I put it in a List and print the contents of the list, the content is still in alphabetical order. I have been solving this for the past week.

```
public void sortPrincipalNameColumn() {
        loginPage.getSampleURL();
        loginPage.loginAction("hello", "password");
 // click Name column to be in reverse alphabetical order  
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"principals-table\"]/thead/tr/th[2]"))).click();
        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td[2]"));
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement e : list){
    strings.add(e.getText());

}
System.out.println(strings);
```

Above is my code. I expected the output to be in reverse alphabetical order but when I printed it, it's still in alphabatical order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702138/what-is-the-method-to-retrieve-the-contents-of-a-column-in-reverse-order-using-s/76704298#76704298

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Collections.reverse(list); before you print it out.

You can read up on it here --> [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-sort-an-ArrayList-in-Java-in-descending-order)