# What is the method to retrieve the contents of a column in reverse order using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As a beginner in Selenium and Java, I have encountered difficulties sorting a dataTable. Specifically, I am attempting to click on the Name column in order to sort it in reverse order, as the default sorting is in alphabetical order. However, even after storing the data in a List and printing its contents, I still see them in alphabetical order [Prestige Park Grove](https://www.prestigesparkgrove.in/). I have been working on this issue for the past week.

```
public void sortPrincipalNameColumn() {
    loginPage.getSampleURL();
    loginPage.loginAction("hello", "password");

    // Click on the Name column to sort it in reverse alphabetical order
    WebElement nameColumn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a"));
    nameColumn.click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    WebElement nameHeader = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"principals-table\"]/thead/tr/th[2]")));
    nameHeader.click();

    List<WebElement> nameElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td[2]"));
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    for (WebElement element : nameElements) {
        names.add(element.getText());
    }

    // Sort the list in reverse order
    Collections.reverse(names);

    System.out.println(names);
}
```

The provided code did not produce the expected output of reverse alphabetical order. Despite the attempt to sort the list in reverse order, the printed output remains in alphabetical order

Comment: can you print *names* before sorting and see if it's fine there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with the way you're trying to sort the list. In your code, I can see you are using Collections.reverse(names) to sort the list in reverse order. However, this method only reverses the existing order of the elements in the list, without actually sorting them in reverse alphabetical order.

To sort the list of names in reverse alphabetical order, you can use the `Collections.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());` method with a ***custom Comparator*** that sorts the elements in reverse order.

**Updated Code:**

```
 Collections.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**Output:**
**[image: Output:]**